# Any reflection is homotopic to the antipodal map on $ \ S^{2n} $.

Tags: algebraic-topology

By the degree argument we see that any reflection on  $\ S^{2n}$ is homotopic to the antipodal map.

But that seems a big theorem. I am looking for a straightforward argument.

Comment: Hint: Consider a suitable path in $\mathrm{O}(2 n + 1)$ from $\textrm{diag}(1, \ldots, 1, -1)$ to $\textrm{diag}(-1, \ldots, -1, -1)$.

Comment: I think you mean a reflection specifically in a hyperplane, right?  For example, reflecting $S^2$ in any axis in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a half-turn about that axis, which is homotopic to the identity map.